# Username overflow in Data Explorer users page

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, design, users-page

Well, [see for yourself](https://data.stackexchange.com/users):

> [image]

On other sites that I checked the user names are trimmed, so it appears to be local problem with the Data Explorer site only.

**Despite being fixed, the fix is still not pushed and the bug still exists.**

Comment: sux2b him if you needed to type your username to login to data.SE

Comment: Soon, Jon Skeet will force us to display rep in hex to save space. This is a premonition of what will follow.

Comment: Nobody cares for poor Buzz Lightyear who is overrun by the cruel GUID? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, I had meant to fix that a while ago before anyone noticed, but I guess I forgot. At any rate, it's fixed in the next build >  2012.9.7.6 (may be a few days).

Comment: Cheers, didn't know you're a dev! :)

Comment: I'm not, just a meddler :) (SEDE is [open source](https://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/))

Comment: Nice, had no idea it's open source.

Comment: Hmm.. version is still 2012.9.7.6 - when and how a build is rolled in there?

Comment: Yeah, someone has to pull the changes and kick off the TeamCity build, which I can't do. I'm on vacation until the 26th, but I'll get it sorted out when I get back.

Comment: Can it be that the team is doing this on purpose i.e. decided to shut down Data Explorer? Site that can't be updated is dead anyway.

Comment: Not at all, they're just busy with other things.

Comment: I see, but still... they will always be busy.

Comment: Heh, I suppose that's true. Believe me, if I could do it myself, I would. :P

Comment: maybe worth trying feature request asking for such a thing?

Comment: Whoops, didn't get properly notified of your last comment. A feature request to update the code? You could do that, I asked directly about doing so a week or so ago and was told there was a lot going on at the moment.

Comment: [You mean this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178288/152859)? :)